# Javascript function is working on firefox only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have the following javascript function:

```
function kitemoving() {
    setInterval(function(){
        kite.animate({
            top: '+=30'
        },{ 
            duration: 1500 
        });
        kite.animate({
            top: '-=30'
        },{ 
            duration: 1500
        });
    });
}
kitemoving();
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anahitdev/wdodmvyu/)

Everywhere it is working fine only on Mozilla Firefox all the movements with this code are being worked only once. Could you help me to understand why?

Comment: No interval time set

Comment: It is strange that it is not working only on mozila

Comment: Added the fiddle @user2181397

Comment: @AnahitDEV Provide jsfiddle working on other browser at least...   http://jsfiddle.net/wdodmvyu/1/  Anyway, that's not the way you should animate it, using an interval. Here you are saturing the fx queue for sure...

Comment: In your fiddle, you need to set the `position` rule on the `.kite` element so that the `top` rule is actually followed.

Comment: **1.** Add timer to setInterval. **2.** Use `position: absolute;` on image. Check [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/wdodmvyu/2/)

Comment: @Tushar I would suggest to use CSS animation :)

Comment: i needed something crossbrowser so that's why i used javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify an interval value that is why Gecko is struggling.

```
function kitemoving() {
    setInterval(function(){
        kite.animate({
            top: '+=30'
        },{ 
            duration: 1500 
        });
        kite.animate({
            top: '-=30'
        },{ 
            duration: 1500
        });
    },300);//interval
}
kitemoving();
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use interval, you could easily saturate the `fx` queue. Instead, use any complete animation callback, e.g:

```
var kite = jQuery('.kite');

function kitemoving() {
    kite.animate({
        top: '+=30'
    }, {
        duration: 1500
    });
    kite.animate({
        top: '-=30'
    }, {
        duration: 1500
    }).promise().done(kitemoving);
}
kitemoving();
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: is recursive setTimeout better than interval and if it is why is that :) sorry for the offtopic qn.

Comment: @vtz Ya recursive timeout would be better in case OP, for some strange reason, wouldn't use animation callback

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a value for the delay parameter.

setInterval expects at least two parameters. Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

> `func` is the function you want to be called repeatedly.
>
> `delay` is the number of milliseconds (thousandths of a second) that the
>   setInterval() function should wait before each call to func. As with
>   setTimeout, there is a minimum delay enforced.
>
> `param1, param2,` and so forth, are additional parameters that are
>   passed through to the function specified by func.

Therefore when you omit the second parameter you can not expect a defined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do in order to make your fiddle work in Firefox, is provide an interval amount to the `setInterval` call

```
setInterval(function(){
    ....
}, 3000);
```

Here is an updated fiddle, which works in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/wdodmvyu/5/

Comment: At least set the rule to more than 3000ms, otherwise this is just increasing the animation queue depth needlessly.